# find all on complex model

Tags: php, cakephp

I just need to get the details from a find all across 4 associated tables. I looked at the docs and I can get the data from 2 tables but not the other tables.
I have a lessons table where I get the relevant tutor id rows to display only. This works fine. I have a lessons-students table related to the lessons table over the FK lessons id. From this lessons-students table I then a field linked to another table.

lessons table (fk tutor_id but no student_id)
tutors table(linked to lessons table with tutor_id)
lessons_students table (linked with lessonID and has a studentID HABTM)
students table(linked with studentID from lesson-students table)

so if I get a row from lessons table I want the tutor name (from tutor table and I can do this now), the student name via the studentID . This is 4 tables and this is proving a headache as the docs just do simple examples. I cant get the student name or student id to  display

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

I tried this and I am guessing as I have a HABTM and a belongsTo relationship.There has to be documented somewhere as I am searching answers in google for hours.

$this->set( 'student',$this->Lesson->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array('Lesson.id' => 2),
    'contain' => array(    'Student' => array('conditions' => array('Student.id' => 'Lesson.id'))))));

```
class LessonsController extends AppController {
   $this->set( 'tutor',$this->Lesson->find('all', array(
             'conditions'=>array('Lesson.Tutor_id'=> 1,'Lesson.id'=>'Lesson_Students.lesson_id') ) ));



view
////////

  <?php 
      foreach ($tutor as $item):

        echo '<tr><td>'. $item['Lesson']['id'].'</td>';
      //  echo '<td>'. $item['Tutor']['id']['username'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $item['Lesson']['tutor_id'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $item['Tutor']['last_name'].'</td>';  
           echo '<td>'. $item['Lesson_Student']['student_id'].'</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';
     endforeach;
     unset($item);
```

Comment: when I do a debug of the find all I do get the students row but i cant seem to print it out the value.   echo '<td>'. $item['Lesson']['Student']['id'] gives an undefined value of student with and without the [lesson] name

Comment: The student table has a HABTM relationship with lessons so how do I get the data out along with the other models. I see the data in the array in debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by adding all needed joins manually to the options array:

```
'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'sales',
        'alias' => 'Sale',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Sale.serialnumber_id = Serialnumber.id'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'rentals',
        'alias' => 'Rental',
        'type' => 'left',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Rental.serialnumber_id = Serialnumber.id'
        )
    ),
)
```

Then you can use all these field in your conditions-array and add them to your fields-array.

To optimize the whole query, you should only retrieve the fields you need - by adding the fields option. A SELECT * query (like this one) is query is slow and creates a lot if useless traffic, especially when you query multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.ok but how can i do this and also get data from a belongsTo table in the same find all?

Comment: I tried the code above in the answer but I cant display the data in the view . I see the array but displaying the data from the view isnt working.... foreach ($student as $item2):
           echo '<td>'. $item2['Student']['id'].'</td>';    //error

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined index: when displaying the data. How do I simply display the data in the view as my code isnt working  foreach ($student as $item2):
           echo '<td>'. $item2['Student']['id'].'</td>';    There has to be a simple answer  to this. HABTM has been awful to use

Comment: I think your problem is, that the recursive level is not high enough. You try to fetch data from the second level. Just add a _'recursive' => 2_ to your options array.

Comment: NO that is not it , recursive values are doing nothing. I really need to get this done so could someone please help me to just get the data displayed from these relationships. I really need to get this done and I am guessing in what to do. Right now I cant even get data from HSBTM to display Notice (8): Undefined index: when displaying the data. How do I simply display the data in the view as my code isnt working foreach ($student as $item2): echo '<td>'. $item2['Student']['id'].'</td>'; There has to be a simple answer to this. HABTM has been awful to use

Comment: If you working with relations with a depth of 2 ore more, you find the data you are searching for also a level deeper. Just add a debug($item2) to your foreach loop and you see all available data.
I guess you find the Student data in $item2['Lesson'][]['Student']

Comment: The answer pointed me in the right direction but it wasnt complete and hence the problem could not be solved. I also needed a field list. I think we were all barking up the wrong tree with recursive and $item2['Lesson'][]['Student']